# react js svg linearGradient not rendering correct value

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, linear-gradients

I have a component where I'm rendering SVG paths and a linearGradient value provided from static data via the parent component. The properties are called 'startColor' & 'stopColor' mainly for the start and stop colours for the gradients.

When I console log the values for each object they are correct however, they are not rendering as expected. Please note the values for dataTwo object are different.

I suspect that on render the first value from the first object is what's used across all components. I've tested this and seems to be the case.

How can I get each circle to render the correct gradient colours provided within data?

Data structure:

```
    const dataOne = [
    {
        title: 'Cpu utilisation',
        graph: 65,
        noBorder: false,
        noMargin: false,
        startColor: '#2DC0FF',
        stopColor: '#0160B2'
    },
    {
        title: 'Memory utilisation',
        graph: 65,
        noBorder: true,
        noMargin: true,
        startColor: '#2DC0FF',
        stopColor: '#0160B2'
    },
]

const dataTwo = [
    {
        title: 'Warnings today',
        graph: 65,
        noBorder: false,
        noMargin: false,
        startColor: '#fa9100',
        stopColor: '#ffc14f'
    },
    {
        title: 'Errors today',
        graph: 65,
        noBorder: true,
        noMargin: true,
        startColor: '#fa9100',
        stopColor: '#ffc14f'
    },
]
```

Component usage:

```
<div className="tab-info-body large">
    <DoubleGraph data={dataOne} />                              
</div>
<div className="tab-info-body large">
    <DoubleGraph data={dataTwo} />                              
</div>
```

Component code:

```
render() {
        const { data, title, startColor, stopColor } = this.props;
        const { value, valueOne, valueTwo, hidden, visible, valueOneYPos, valueTwoYPos, valueOneHidden, valueTwoHidden, dashArray, dashArrayBorder } = this.state;
        const styleOne = { transform: `translate(0px, ${valueOneYPos}px)` };
        const styleTwo = { transform: `translate(0px, ${valueTwoYPos}px)` };

        return (
            <div className="double-graph-wrap">
                <div className="flex">
                    {data.map((item, i) => {
                        console.log("give me colour", item.startColor)
                        return (
                            <div className={classNames('wrap', { noBorder: item.noBorder, noMargin: item.noMargin})}>
                                {i === 1 &&<div className="border-test"></div>}
                                <span className="title">{item.title}</span>
                                <div className="graph-wrap">
                                    <div className="graph">
                                        <div className="value-wrap">
                                            <div className="values">
                                                <span style={styleOne} className={classNames("valueOne", {hidden: valueOneHidden})}>{valueOne}</span>
                                                <span style={styleTwo} className={classNames("valueTwo", {hidden: valueTwoHidden})}>{valueTwo}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="single-chart">
                                            <div style={{ background: 'black', width: 100, height: 100}}>{item.startColor}</div>
                                            <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
                                            <defs>
                                              <linearGradient id='grad'>
                                                <stop stop-color={item.startColor} />
                                                <stop offset='100%' stop-color={item.stopColor} />
                                              </linearGradient>
                                              </defs>
                                                <path class="circle-bg"
                                                    d="M18 2.0845
                                                    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                                    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
                                                />
                                                    <path class="borderTwo"
                                                    stroke-dasharray={dashArrayBorder}
                                                    d="M18 2.0845
                                                    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831 
                                                    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
                                                />
                                                <path class="circle"
                                                    stroke-dasharray={dashArray}
                                                    d="M18 2.0845
                                                    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831 
                                                    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
                                                />
                                                <path class="borderOne"
                                                    stroke-dasharray="1, 100"
                                                    d="M18 2.0845
                                                    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831 
                                                    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
                                                />
                                                <path class="average"
                                                stroke-dasharray="1, 100"
                                                    d="M18 2.0845
                                                    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831"
                                                />
                                            </svg>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: use unique id values rather than hardcoding id='grad'

Comment: This was great thank you, I added an id to the data object, listened to the id and change the parent className based on the ID to render the correct stroke. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well and the issue and fix [Filth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665312/filth) mentioned helped me quite a bit.

The real issue here is that the browser expects the id to be unique. 
The result from this might depend on the browser (we noticed a difference between chrome and safari).

Having the same id's ([see it here](https://jsfiddle.net/CynderRnAsh/rgdzsye3/14/)) uses the same color gradient for all circles in chrome (83.0.4103.97 debian).

You can actually see this by running document.getElementById("yourid") you should notice the element is the one thats used for all the gradients.

Note: To simplify things i added a fill.

```
                        <path
                      class="average"
                      stroke-dasharray="1, 100"
                      d="M18 2.0845 a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831"
                      fill={`url(#${item.id})`}
```

The fix for this was just to use a unique id for the fill [see it working here](https://jsfiddle.net/CynderRnAsh/rgdzsye3/10/)